# ruby variable scoping error in text adventure

Tags: ruby, scope

Here is the code I'm working on.

```
def gold_room
  puts "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

  print "> "
  choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

  # this line has a bug, so fix it
  if choice.include?("0") || choice.include?("1")
    how_much = choice.to_i
  else
    dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
  end

  if how_much < 50
    puts "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
    exit(0)
  else
    dead("You greedy bastard!")
  end
end

def bear_room
  puts "There is a bear here."
  puts "The bear has a bunch of honey."
  puts "The fat bear is in front of another door."
  puts "How are you going to move the bear?"
  bear_moved = false

  while true
    print "> "
    choice = $stdin.gets.chomp
    if choice == "take honey"
      dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
    elsif choice == "taunt bear" && !bear_moved
      puts "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
      bear_moved == true
    elsif choice == "taunt bear" && bear_moved
      dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
    elsif (choice == "open door") && bear_moved
      gold_room
    else
      puts "I got no idea what that means."
    end
  end
end

def cthulhu_room
  puts "Here you see the great evil Cthulhu."
  puts "He, it, whatever stares at you and you go insane."
  puts "Do you flee for your life or eat your head?"

  print "> "
  choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

  if choice.include? "flee"
    start
  elsif choice.include? "head"
    dead("Well that was tasty!")
  else
    cthulhu_room
  end
end

def dead(why)
  puts why, "Good job!"
  exit(0)
end

def start
  puts "You are in a dark room."
  puts "There is a door to your right and left."
  puts "Which one do you take?"

  print "> "
  choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

  if choice == "left"
    bear_room
  elsif choice == "right"
    cthulhu_room
  else
    dead("You stumble around the room until you starve.")
  end
end

start
```

When I try to run it in my terminal on OS X, I get this:

```
You are in a dark room.
There is a door to your right and left.
Which one do you take?
> left
There is a bear here.
The bear has a bunch of honey.
The fat bear is in front of another door.
How are you going to move the bear?
> taunt bear
The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now.
> open door
I got no idea what that means.  # should go to gold_room, new area
>
```

I expected the program to take me to the gold room after typing in "open door", but instead it goes to the barf messages and restarts the while loop.

I assume I have messed up something with scope, but I did research and still don't understand why the variable wasn't manipulated, or why I'm not getting the result I expect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". We need a better description of the problem. What's it not doing correctly? Your code example won't give us that output.

Comment: I note that your "elsif" syntax is different for the last three conditions: two have parentheses, which may change the evaluation order.  Please check that.  Also, please check that your entry of "open door" does not contain any blanks: a simple **puts** should show this, such as **puts "|", choice, "|"**.
When you have trouble with your program logic, at least trace the data and control flows with some print statements before you look elsewhere for help; debugging is a very useful skill.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may be that you wrote `bear_moved == true` instead of `bear_moved = true`.

Answer (score 1):

it's `bear_moved = true` not `bear_moved == true`

```
elsif choice == "taunt bear" && !bear_moved
      puts "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
      bear_moved = true
elsif choice == "taunt bear" && bear_moved
```

Answer (score 0):

The `bear_moved` variable should receive the boolean, instead comparing it with `true` at the 14th line of method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to ensure that when bear is taunted and it does not move it should move bear, not check again if bear moved.
The solution should be to remove the comparison operator on `elsif choice == "taunt bear" && !bear_moved` change the bear_moved to `=` not `==`

```
 while true
    print "> "
    choice = $stdin.gets.chomp
    if choice == "take honey"
      dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
    elsif choice == "taunt bear" && !bear_moved
      puts "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
      bear_moved = true
    elsif choice == "taunt bear" && bear_moved
      dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
    elsif (choice == "open door") && bear_moved
      gold_room
    else
      puts "I got no idea what that means."
    end
  end
```